# Full Calendar + Filter Displayed Data Possible?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, events, fullcalendar

I am currently using event_calendar but leaning more towards FullCalendar as it allows for auto height when multiple events are added for a given week.

My current setup has an event calendar associated to a each location within my application. So when it a user loads a particular location, it own renders the events associated with the location being viewed.

I have messed with and implemented Full Calendar but was wondering since the url points to /events, is there a way to only display the events associated with a particular location?

Right now, all events are displaying on all location calendars.

Thanks!

**Adding More Detail**

Here is my current setup with event calendar that is allowing me to filter the events associated with each location

**Event Model**

```
belongs_to :location
has_event_calendar
```

**Location Model**

```
has_many :events
```

**Location Controller "Show"**

```
def show
   @month = (params[:month] || (Time.zone || Time).now.month).to_i
   @year = (params[:year] || (Time.zone || Time).now.year).to_i
   @shown_month = Date.civil(@year, @month)
   @event_strips = @location.events.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month)
end
```

**Location "Show View"**

```
<div class="span8">                           
   <%= raw(event_calendar) %>
</div>
```

Now how to I go about filtering the same data for full calendar since displaying as JSON looks at the events "index" for the data?

**Full Calendar Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    height: 500,

    // a future calendar might have many sources.
    eventSources: [{
        url: '/events', // Shows all events BUT need it to show only events to certain location
        color: 'yellow',
        textColor: 'black',
        ignoreTimezone: false
    }],

    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5",

    );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using [events as a json feed](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) you can change include extra parameters in the url property to filter on the server

If you can't filter on the server you could use [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) to filter on the client (just hide elements you don't want to display)

From your edit it looks like you want to load all events and hide some events based on a selected location, so I think you should use eventRender to filter the events. If the location is changed then call [rerenderEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/) (from within a change or click function related to the control that has changed) which will again call eventRender and apply the filter you already have in place. I don't think this will call the json feed again but you might want to verify this.

```
...
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if (event.belongs_to !== $('#locationControl').val()) {
        $(element).hide();
    } else {
        // Not sure if you need this
        $(element).show();
    }
}...


$('#locationControl').change(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' )
}):
```

Comment: Added more details for your review

Comment: I think I am just simply lost in how to inform the calendar that I am visiting a certain location and then only displaying that locations events

Comment: Rather than using $(element).hide(), return false from eventRender to stop the event from being rendered at all. This has the advantage that it will not leave an empty space where the event is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

In my application I have filtered events at server side.

You can pass a parameter to events URL say locationid. Filter events in server side function based on that locationid & return those events.